# Passing array with Ajax to PHP script results in empty post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to pass an array from a HTML site to a PHP script using AJAX

**JS**

```
function selectPictures() {
    //selected Pictures is my JS array
    var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(selectedPictures);

    var request;
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "selectedPictures.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            data: jsonArray
        },
        cache: false
        success: function () {
            alert('OK');
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
href="selectedPictures.php" onclick="selectPictures();"
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
    foreach($data as $d) {
        echo $d;
    }
}
```

Actually I want to send the data to another HTML page and then include the PHP script, but I don't understand why this example does not even work. The `$_POST['data']` is not set.

**UPDATE**
Ok, the Ajax post is actually working, as I see the HTTP request is successful **BUT:** I cannot access the variable instantly. I need to access the values of the passed array at once to execute another PHP script. When I want to do this, I get an undefined index error. Also at the time when the isset function is executed, it returns false (despite the successful HTTP request).

Comment: And where is defined `selectedPictures` ??

Comment: Does the OK alert show?

Comment: please insert a var_dump($_POST) at the top of your PHP file, to see if you actually receive something. if not, you can concentrate on the JS to find the problem.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing received. That's why I'm wondering if something is wrong with the concept or the Ajax request. If I fill the array manually it does not work as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="selectPictures">click</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
  $('#selectPictures').click(function(){
    var jsonArray = JSON.stringify(selectedPictures);   
    var request = $.ajax({
    url: "selectedPictures.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {data: jsonArray},
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){alert(data);}
    });
  });
});
```

Use f12 in chrome to see errors, you forgot to add a comma after the "cache: false"

Comment: Thanks, now the 'OK' alert shows up but I still don't get the data in my PHP script, i.e. the else part of the isset function is still executed.

Comment: u get it, u can see it in network tab in chrome dev tools.
or replace success to: function(data){alert(data);}

Comment: Oh, you are right, I was confused because var_dump[POST] still showed array(0). Thanks

Comment: Ok, then how come the isset is still false?

Comment: var selectedPictures is not empty? i check it in my localhost it work fine if i replace "selectedPictures" with something like this {"ar":"ar"}

Comment: you are absolutely right, but I still cannot directly access the passed variable -> see the updated question

Comment: so do you have any other idea, why it's not working?

Comment: try to remove stripslashes it can crash your json, use [json_last_error()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to see json error